Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
I have deployed my smart contract on Base Mainnet, and when i try to verify it on Basescan, I keep getting this error message:
"Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])
 For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

Compiler Warning(s):

ParserError: Source "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:4:1:
  |
4 | import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ParserError: Source "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:5:1:
  |
5 | import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"

I used remix to deploy, and compiled using 0.8.20, with MIT license. Also, I have tried to verify using the "CONTRACT VERIFICATION" plugin on remix, and that's stuck in "pending" despite Base Mainnet not currently undergoing maintenance.
Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Try flattening the contract, ie copy and paste everything into a single file. Use the same number of optimisations then try again. | If you have constructor arguments it will likely fail and show both outputs, copy the ending of the one they say they are looking for (from where yours stops to the end) and paste that in the encoded constructor argument section.

can i flatten the contract by pressing right click on my .sol file and selecting "flatten"? and when you say "try again" do you mean i should compile and deploy the contract again after flattening it?

I don't mean deploy again. No idea on a flatten abstraction, try it and see. I mean literally copy and paste all the source into a single file or into the verification window, because the explorers don't handle imports well. Then click verify again, and see if it works or complains that the resulting bytecode is a little different.

so, doing right click and "flatten" didnt work as it was saying that its looking the SPDX license identifier upon verify. instead i copied and pasted the import contracts from github, and now i get this error:
ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
--> myc:20:1:
|
20 | import {Context} from "../utils/Context.sol"
| ^^^^^^
if you can help?

ok so i pasted in the contract for context.sol, and now the error i get it this:
"ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
--> myc:30:1:
|
30 | abstract contract Context {
| ^^^^^^^^

It sounds like maybe you paste interface sections inside contract sections by mistake. Did you paste them where you would have had the import lines? So you can see them as independent contracts one after the other? It should be no different to if you find and replace the import lines with the source code files.

ok so ive gone back and pasted every contract where there is an import line, and this error code comes back:
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
--> myc:594:1:
|
594 | abstract contract Context {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: The previous declaration is here:
--> myc:109:1:
|
109 | abstract contract Context {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

To be honest I feel too far removed from the source to work through compilation errors. If you want to add links for all the source and the contract address. Then I (or some one else) can potentially work through the issues first hand.

basically, the only error coming up at this point is to do with not pasting the ownable.sol contract in. so, i have now pasted that in, and the error shown is now coming up. its to do with the ownable.sol paste. any ideas?error code:
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
--> myc:590:1:
|
590 | abstract contract Context {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: The previous declaration is here:
--> myc:107:1:
|
107 | abstract contract Context {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

so it appears that i had pasted context.sol in twice, as another contract calls it too, so ive deleted one of them, and now i get just get the error code that says "bytecode we were looking for vs what we got". i feel like im close. where do i go from here?

can you try verifying with hardhat instead?

i dont know, ive never used it. is it easy? Im a finance guy who has come into smart contracts via meme coins, so the learning curve for coding has been insanely steep, and i would still consider myself utterly useless.
